# ADMX not loaded from Central Store

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

I've create a central policy store as shown below:

[image]

Afterwards I copied all files into the new folder:

[image]

However, when I want to create a new gpo, the templates are loaded not from the central store:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, if you write `PolicyDefinitions` instead of `PolicyDefitions` it works.